# replacing NA's in a Large POSIXct with Sys.time()

Tags: r, posixct, posixlt

I have a `large POSIXct` of around 70,000 elements.

```
resolutionDate <- c(as.POSIXct(data$Resolution.Date, format = '%b %d, %Y'))
```

The code above changes the values from `Jun 5, 2018 3:21 PM` to `2018-06-05`.

However, some values are `NA` and I would like to replace all `NA`'s with `Sys.time()`, for today's date.

I tried using the `replace()` method as so,
`replace(resolutionDate, if(resolutionData == "NA"), Sys.time())`

But did not work..

How can I do this?

Comment: I think if the format is the same for all the values, it should be `format = '%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p'`

Comment: use `ifelse(is.na(resolutionData$resolutionDate), Sys.time(), resolutionData$resolutionDate)`, use `is.na` rather than `== ` also, please aware about the formats of dates as pointed in previous comment by akrun

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
# generate time vector
a <- as.POSIXct(1:70000,origin="1970-01-01")
# replace the 5th with a NA value and show first 10 elements
a[5] <- NA
a[1:10]
# replace all na values with the current system time
a[is.na(a)] <- Sys.time()
# show result
a[1:10]
```